# Jetpack compose preview not working after android studio update to electric eel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-electric-eel

[image]

I have updated android stuido to the latest version electric eel, my composables preview is not working. `Missing classes` error is found.
need help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the build variant to `debug`
2. `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project

This will fix the issue.